# Auto Update Columns in DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Hello  i m using List as datasource in WPF C#. there are feilds like Rate , weight , Quantity .

My need is to update Quantity automatically when i change value of rate or weight.....

All i need when i update rate , bags, weight then amount or respective quantity change automatically...

My Code ....

XAML :

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGridItem" LoadingRow="dataGridItem_LoadingRow" Binding.XmlNamespaceManager="{Binding}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="292" Width="740" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
        <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=Header}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
        <DataGrid.Columns>    
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding I_ID}" Visibility="Hidden"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding I_Code}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Grade" Binding="{Binding I_Grade}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Particulars" Binding="{Binding I_Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rate" Binding="{Binding I_Rate}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bags" Binding="{Binding I_BAGS}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Weight" Binding="{Binding I_WEIGHT_BAGS}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding I_QUANTITY}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Binding="{Binding I_Amount}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

C# :

```
public class cls_INVOICE_ITEM
{
    public int _I_ID;
    public string _I_Code;
    public string _I_Grade;
    public string _I_Name;
    public decimal _I_Rate;
    public decimal _I_BAGS = 0;
    public decimal _I_WEIGHT_BAGS = 0;
    public decimal _I_QUANTITY;
    public decimal _I_RATE = 0;
    public decimal _I_Amount;
    public int I_ID { get { return _I_ID; } set { _I_ID = value; } }
    public string I_Code { get { return _I_Code; } set { _I_Code = value; } }
    public string I_Grade { get { return _I_Grade; } set { _I_Grade = value; } }
    public string I_Name { get { return _I_Name; } set { _I_Name = value; } }
    public decimal I_Rate { get { return _I_Rate; } set { _I_Rate = value; } }
    public decimal I_BAGS { get { return _I_BAGS; } set { _I_BAGS = value; } }
    public decimal I_WEIGHT_BAGS { get { return _I_WEIGHT_BAGS; } set { _I_WEIGHT_BAGS = value; } }
    public decimal I_QUANTITY { get { return I_BAGS * I_WEIGHT_BAGS; } set { _I_QUANTITY = I_BAGS * I_WEIGHT_BAGS; } }
    public decimal I_Amount { get { return I_BAGS * I_WEIGHT_BAGS * I_Rate; } set { _I_Amount = I_BAGS * I_WEIGHT_BAGS * I_Rate; } }
}

static List<cls_INVOICE_ITEM> lstIOrder = new List<cls_INVOICE_ITEM>();

DataTable DT = BLL.Get_Item_By_ItemCode(txtItemCode.Text);           


Function Which BindData :

        if(DT.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            lstIOrder.Add(new cls_INVOICE_ITEM() { I_ID = int.Parse((DT.Rows[0]["I_ID"].ToString())), I_Code = DT.Rows[0]["I_Code"].ToString(), I_Grade = DT.Rows[0]["I_Grade"].ToString(), I_Name = DT.Rows[0]["I_Name"].ToString() });
        }
        dataGridItem.ItemsSource = null;
        dataGridItem.ItemsSource = lstIOrder;
```

Comment: Use INotifyPropertyChanged. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: As @Ayyappan said. Write a readonly property `Quantity` that returns the calculated value. When either of the contributing values changes, raise PropertyChanged("Quantity"). More on INotifyPropertyChanged: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1316417/424129

Comment: Quantity is changed.... But i also want to change Amount?????????